# How to filter based on the some part of a value of rows in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter

I have a pandas dataframe as below:

```
   +------+---+
   |Name  |age|
   +------+---+
   |Mona  |12 |
   +------+---+
   |Monika|25 |
   +------+---+
   |Tomas |3  |
   +------+---+
   |Ilyas |47 |
   +------+---+
```

Now, I want to assign some values in a new column to the `Name` column contains some substring. For example if it contains Mon then we assign `text` to them and if it contains `as` we assign `city` to them.

So the output must be:

```
   +------+---+----+
   |Name  |age|new |
   +------+---+----+
   |Mona  |12 |text|
   +------+---+----+
   |Monika|25 |text|
   +------+---+----+
   |Tomas |3  |city|
   +------+---+----|
   |Ilyas |47 |city|
   +------+---+----+
```

I wrote the following codes and it didn't work:

```
df['new'] = np.nan    
df['new'] = df['new'].mask( 'Mon' in df['Name'], 'text')    
df['new'] = df['new'].mask( 'as' in df['Name'], 'city')
```

Comment: And what if the word is `Monas`? Does priority go to the first condition or last? Your attempt seems to indicate the latter.

Answer (score 1):

If your logic is going to get complicated, you may want to encapsulate your mapping into a function:

```
def map_func(name):
    if 'Mon' in name:
        return 'text'
    elif 'as' in name:
        return 'city'

df['Name'].map(map_func)
```

Result:

```
0    text
1    text
2    city
3    city
Name: Name, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do:

```
df['new']=np.where(df.Name.str.contains('Mon'), 'text', 'city')
```

`np.where` works like Excel's `IF` : if the condition is met, fill with 'text', else fill with 'city'.

Comment: I think in this case, nested `where` or `select`, since it seems that `NaN` should be filled when neither `Mon` nor `as` are found (i.e. the column is initialized as `df['new'] = np.nan`)

Comment: That's right. I'm not quite sure how to do it without starting nesting `np.where`s, though

Answer (score 0):

```py
Df.loc[df.name.str.endswith('as'), 'new'] = 'city'
Df.loc[df.name.str.startswith('Mon'), 'new'] = 'text'
```

Str has a method startsWith and endsWith for that kind of problems. 
There's probably the way to do it in a single line but right now nothing comes to my mind.

Loc is always helpful with selecting and updating data on condition.

Edit: Juan C is right it should be 'contains' not 'startsWith', my bad.

Answer (score 0):

I think this would be your best bet, since it will handle case-insensitive matches and fill `NaN` where neither condition is met.

```
import numpy as np

     Name  Age
0    Mona   12
1  Monika   25
2   Tomas    3
3   Ilyas   47

default = np.where(df.Name.str.contains('as', case=False), 'city', np.nan)
cond = np.where(df.Name.str.contains('Mon', case=False), 'text', default)

df.assign(new=cond)

     Name  Age   new
0    Mona   12  text
1  Monika   25  text
2   Tomas    3  city
3   Ilyas   47  city
```